# How to make scrollable box in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a `Card` widget, which looks like:

[image]

But when the number in it gets bigger, it overflows the `Card` like so:

[image]

I tried to wrap the text-box in a `SizedBox` and gave it a height. Then, wrapped it in a `SingleChildScrollView` but it didn't help. How should I solve this?

The following is the code:

```
Card(
 child: Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  width: 300,
  height: 250,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      const Text('Output', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25)),
      const SizedBox(height: 10),
      getOutputRow('Answer'),
    ],
  ),
),
```

The helper methods:

```
  Text styledText(String data) {
    return Text(data, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20));
  }

  Widget getOutputBox() {
    final themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final output = result == null ? '' : result.toString();

    return Container(
      width: 150,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 1, color: themeData.primaryColor)),
      child: Text(output, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16), textAlign: TextAlign.center),
    );
  }

  Row getOutputRow(String data) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        styledText(data),
        styledText('='),
        getOutputBox(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SizedBox(
height : 400,
width : 400,
child : SingleChildScrollView(
   child : getOutputRow('Answer')
)
)
```

Comment: Tried that. Then I get this exception: `A RenderFlex overflowed by 792 pixels on the bottom.`

Comment: Also tried adding SizedBox with some height around the row. Then, the row was static. It was not scrollable.

Answer (score 2):

This will help

```
Expanded(
  child:SingleChildScrollView(
     child : getOutputRow('Answer')
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the `Container()` in your `getOutputBox()`

- Put a `SingleChildScrollView` around your Text()
- Algo give the Container a fixed height like: `height: 150`

Try this version

```
  Widget getOutputBox() {
    final themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final output = result == null ? '' : result.toString();

    return Container(
      width: 150,
      height: 150,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 1, 
          color: themeData.primaryColor)),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Text(output,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16), 
              textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
    );
  }
```